# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR with script from sharrre.php

Tags: php

I need to run this script on my site and I have no experience at all with PHP

When I call the following script

```
<?php
  //Sharrre by Julien Hany
  $json = array('url'=>'','count'=>0);
  $json['url'] = $_GET['url'];
  $url = urlencode($_GET['url']);
  $type = urlencode($_GET['type']);

  if(filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    if($type == 'googlePlus'){  //source http://www.helmutgranda.com/2011/11/01/get-a-url-google-count-via-php/
      $content = parse("https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=".$url."&count=true");

      $dom = new DOMDocument;
      $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
      @$dom->loadHTML($content);
      $domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
      $newDom = new DOMDocument;
      $newDom->formatOutput = true;

      $filtered = $domxpath->query("//div[@id='aggregateCount']");
      $json['count'] = str_replace('>', '', $filtered->item(0)->nodeValue);
    }
    else if($type == 'stumbleupon'){
      $content = parse("http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=$url");

      $result = json_decode($content);
      $json['count'] = $result->result->views;
      if( !isset($json['count']) ) $json['count'] = 0;
    }
    else if($type == 'pinterest'){
      $content = parse("http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=&url=$url");

      $result = json_decode(str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('', ''), $content));
      $json['count'] = $result->count;
      if( !isset($json['count']) ) $json['count'] = 0;
    }
  }
  echo str_replace('\\/','/',json_encode($json));

  function parse($encUrl){
    $options = array(
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
      CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'sharrre', // who am i
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5, // timeout on connect
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10, // timeout on response
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3, // stop after 10 redirects
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    );
    $ch = curl_init();

    $options[CURLOPT_URL] = $encUrl;  
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($errmsg != '' || $err != '') {
      /*print_r($errmsg);
      print_r($errmsg);*/
    }
    return $content;
  }
?>
```

I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR on line 20
```

line 20

```
$json['count'] = str_replace('>', '', $filtered->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

Any suggestions to help me figure that problem.

Thank you.

This is the link to the file 
https://bizonbytes.com/miscellaneous/sharrre.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbizonbytes.com%2F&type=googlePlus

I also have a test file to make sure php is working
https://bizonbytes.com/miscellaneous/test.php

I updated the php version to 5 and it works now when I run 
http://bizonbytes.com/miscellaneous/sharrre.php

but if I try the following
https://bizonbytes.com/miscellaneous/sharrre.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbizonbytes.com%2F&type=googlePlus

I get the following error:

```
Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\bizonbytes.com\httpdocs\miscellaneous\sharrre.php on line 56
{"url":"https://bizonbytes.com/","count":""}
```

I've look inside the ini file and its marked safe_mode = off and I'm not sure what to put for open_basedir

Comment: Does your XPath query return any results? If not, I would think `item(0)` wouldn't exist (and thus wouldn't be an object).

Comment: @Wiseguy: But that would not create a *parse* error, or would it?

Comment: @FelixKling I think you're right. I would expect "trying to [do something] on a non-object" instead.

Comment: I don't get a parse error with a cut and paste of this code. Perhaps a really old PHP version? Or an error (like a missing close quote) in a file that includes this?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Good thought. PHP 4 wouldn't allow chaining like this. _Update:_ Yep, OP added a link that shows PHP 4.4.9.

Comment: Then that's your problem. PHP 4 is quite old and unsupported. You need PHP 5.

Comment: ok thanks I will update it and try again

Comment: I've look inside the ini file and its marked safe_mode = off not sure what to put for open_basedir

Comment: @Yannick Since the original question has been answered, you should probably ask this new as a completely new question so that people will see it and answer it. (also because it's unrelated to the original question)

Answer (score 1):

The method chaining feature used here was not introduced until version 5:

```
$filtered->item(0)->nodeValue
```

You'll need a more modern version in order to run this code. Alternatively, you could manually unstack the calls into temporary variables:

```
$temp = $filtered->item(0);
$json['count'] = str_replace('>', '', $temp->nodeValue);
```

*(Striking out previous incorrect answer:)*

> This is your error:
>
> ```
> $filtered->item(0)->nodeValue
> ```
>
> I'm guessing it should be:
>
> ```
> $filtered->item[0]->nodeValue
> ```
>
> I.e., referencing the first element of an array, versus calling a
>   method on an object.

Comment: No, [`item` is a method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), and even if it was an array, it would not throw a **parse** error, but a runtime error.

Comment: Yep, gotcha, just fund that same page. Nuts, looked like an easy one.